# Get error Thread 1 SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, crash, sigabrt

I'm using CoreData in my app. Now add a new entry and try to save it. I don't know why but it fails with `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

This is my saving part:

```
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {

        abort()
    }
```

It crashes in this line of code:

```
        abort()
```

Does someone know why this happens and hoc I can solve it? I also use iCloud Sync if this could be a reason. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Your `save` call failed. More information can be found in the `error` parameter you're passing in, but you have to look at it to see what it says.

Comment: You are shooting yourself in the foot and then complaining that your foot got shot.

Answer (score 1):

Your code behaves exactly as intended. Google for "Unix abort".

NAME

abort - generate an abnormal process abort
 SYNOPSIS

## include

void abort(void);

DESCRIPTION

The abort() function causes abnormal process termination to occur, unless the signal SIGABRT is being caught and the signal handler does not return. The abnormal termination processing includes at least the effect of fclose() on all open streams, and message catalogue descriptors, and the default actions defined for SIGABRT. The SIGABRT signal is sent to the calling process as if by means of raise() with the argument SIGABRT.
The status made available to wait() or waitpid() by abort() will be that of a process terminated by the SIGABRT signal. The abort() function will override blocking or ignoring the SIGABRT signal.

RETURN VALUE

The abort() function does not return.
 ERRORS

No errors are defined.
 EXAMPLES

None.
 APPLICATION USAGE

Catching the signal is intended to provide the application writer with a portable means to abort processing, free from possible interference from any implementation-provided library functions. If SIGABRT is neither caught nor ignored, and the current directory is writable, a core dump may be produced.
 FUTURE DIRECTIONS

None.
 SEE ALSO

exit(), kill(), raise(), signal(),
DERIVATION

Derived from Issue 1 of the SVID.